# Can I disable Interrupts on a BBB for a short duration (0.5ms)?

Tags: arm, interrupt, beagleboneblack

I am trying to write a small driver program on a Beaglebone Black that needs to send a signal with timings like this:

[image]

I need to send 360 bits of information. I'm wondering if I can turn off all interrupts on the board for a duration of 500µs while I send the signal.  I have no idea if I can just turn off all the interrupts like that. Searches have been unkind to me so far. **Any ideas how I might achieve this?** I do have some prototypes in assembly language for the signal, but I'm pretty sure its being broken by interrupts.

So for example, I'm hoping I could have something like this:

```
disable_irq();
/* asm code to send my bytes */
reenable_irq();
```

What would the bodies of disable_irq() and reenable_irq() look like?

Comment: I don't know the specifics of the Beagleboard, but hardware interrupts are generally designed so they ALWAYS interrupt whatever the CPU is doing and call their respective handlers.

Comment: I believe that its quite common for a device driver to temporarily disable irq while it does its business. There are mbed libraries that do this very thing.

Comment: Forgive me, I do not know how to answer your question. I just wanted to ask how I could go about learning this. Is there a textbook I could buy that will teach me how to write driver programs like this?

Comment: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ihi0048b/index.html might be of interest. You'll most likely need to do some calls in assembly.

Answer (score 6):

The calls you would want to use are `local_irq_disable()` and `local_irq_enable()` to disable & enable IRQs locally on the current CPU.  This also has the effect of disabling all preemption on the CPU.

Now lets talk about your general approach.  If I understand you correctly, you'd like to bit bang your protocol over a GPIO with timing accurate to < 1/3 us.

This will be a challenge.  [Tests show](http://hackaday.com/2013/12/07/speeding-up-beaglebone-black-gpio-a-thousand-times/) that the Beaglebone black GPIO toggle frequency is going to max out at ~2.78MHz writing directly to the SoC IO registers in kernel mode (~0.18 us minimum pulse width).

So, although this *might* be achievable by the thinnest of margins by writing atomic code in kernel space,  I propose another concept:

**Implement your custom serial protocol on the SPI bus.**

*Why?*

The SPI bus can be clocked up to 48MHz on the Beaglebone Black, its buffered and can be used with the DMA engine.  Therefore, you don't have to worry about disabling interrupts and monopolizing your CPU for this one interface.  With a timing resolution of ~0.021us (@ 48MHz), you should be able to achieve your timing needs with an acceptable margin of error.

With the bus configured for Single Channel Continuous Transfer Transmit-Only Master mode and 30-bit word length (2 30-bit words for each bit of your protocol):

To write a '0' with your protocol, you'd write the 2 word sequence - 17 '1's followed by 43 '0's - on SPI (@48MHz).

To write a '1' with your protocol, you'd write the 2 word sequence - 43 '1's followed by 17 '0's - on SPI (@48MHz).

Answer (score 1):

From your signal timmings it's easy to figure out that SPI or other serial peripheral can **not** reach your demand. In your timmings, encoding is based on the width of the pulse. So let's get to the point:

> **Q1** Could you turn off all interrupts for a duration of 500µs?

**A:** 0.5ms is quite a long time in embedded system. ISR is born to enable the concurrency of multi-task and improve the real-time capability. Your should keep in mind that ISR and context-switch(in some chip architecture) are all influenced by global interrupt.
But if your top priority is to perform the timmings, and the **real-time window** of other tasks are acceptable, of cause you can disable the global interrupt in the duration. Even longer. If not, don't do ATOM operation in such a long time.

> **Q2** How?

**A:** For a certain chip, there's asm instruction for open/close global interrupt undoubtedly. Find the instructions or the APIs provided by your OS, do the 3 steps below(pseudocode):

```
state_t tState = get_interrupt_status( );
disable_interrupt( );
... /*your operation here*/
resume_interrupt( tState );
```